# Shopify discount on variants based

Tags: shopify

i want to apply discount based on variants on shopify product for example

1) We have a product and it have variant 
2) When more than three variants are added to cart discount is applied on the price of this product 
3) For example if 3 variants then 5% discount if 4 variants then 10% discount and if more than 5 then 15% discount 
4) how this can be done in shopify any help will be appreciated

Comment: Better you find more in Shopify documentation and Supporting staff.

Comment: Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If your store is on [the Plus plan](https://www.shopify.com/plus) then you can can accomplish this using [Shopify Scripts](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/shopify-scripts). There are some example scripts here that you can model yours off of → https://github.com/Shopify/scripts-examples